# Form 2 textbox displays in form 1 listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have two forms, one to display information when a user is selected from the listbox(the listbox lists names, when selected it will fill a few textboxes I have, one for city and another for address), the second form allows me to input the information for the user, which when I click submit will display them in my listbox on form1.  Currently I am able to add the user from my second form to my first form into the listbox, but I am having issues filling their information in the textbox whenever I click on their names in my listbox.

As of now I have tried implementing different code snippets, but being a beginner I'm not sure how to do this.

My first form is as follows

```
 public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void ButtonAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 form = new Form2(textBoxFirstName.Text, listBoxUsers);
   form.Owner = this;
   form.ShowDialog();
   form.Show();
}

private void listBoxUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (listBoxUser.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
      User selected = (User)listBoxUser.SelectedItem;
      textBoxStreet.Text = selected.Street;
      textBoxCity.Text = selected.City;
    }
}
```

My second form where I add the users information is as follows

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   private ListBox _listBoxUsers;
   public Form(string value, ListBox listBoxUser)
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     value=($"{textBoxFirstName.Text} {textBoxLastName.Text}");
     _listBoxUsers = listBoxUsers;
   }

   private void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      _listBoxUsers.Items.Add($"{textBoxFirstName.Text} 
      {textBoxLastName.Text}");

      this.Close();
   }

}
```

And my Class where I am trying to store the textbox information

```
public class User : EventArgs
{
     public string Street {get; set;}
     public string City {get;set;}

    public User(string street, string city)
  {
     Street = street;
     City = city;
  }

}
```

In Short:  I'm trying to save information from my second form into my class, and when I select a user from my listbox it will display his street and city into textboxes (my listbox and textboxes are both on my first form.).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second form you should be creating User object and fill the details like street and city .

```
private void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User(textBoxFirstName.Text, textBoxLastName.Text);
    _listBoxUsers.Items.Add(user);

    this.Close();
}
```

Since Listbox.Items expecting object type, you can add anything which is derived from System.Object. But in the form1 you have created list with User Objects and during selected index changed you are type casting as User Object. But in the form2 you have not actually inserted User object during the submit button click .

Because of this, i think you are facing this problem . Try with above code and check

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197016/discussion-on-answer-by-praveen-m-form-2-textbox-displays-in-form-1-listbox).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest decoupling state management from the presentation. For example, try to create a separate class for `User` that is not derived from `EventArgs`. And manage its state inside a separate class - for start int will be in-memory storage. But as you flesh out your implementation you can latter move your data to Database with ease as it will not rely on UI and its elements for storage and management.